# How to access and modify the Action Bar content from within another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, task

I’m making some experiments to make experience with threads and tasks in Android development using Android Studio latest version on Windows 10 Pro x64.  I wrote two versions of a very simple app with two buttons to show how it is important to use separated threads for very heavy works so that the app doesn’t hang: with one button I can change the layout background color and with the other button I start a counter that counts from 0 to 10000000 showing the incremental value on the Action Bar. This counter can stuck the responsiveness of the app for seconds so when It starts and until it ends is not possible to change the background color. This is a case where is a good idea to create a separated task for this heavy job.

The two versions of the app differ because the first one doesn’t have a separated task for the counter (so that can be experienced the not responsiveness of the app during the counting) and the second one does.

This is the source code of the first version:

```
package com.example.testasync;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    int flagBackgroundColor = 0;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Counter: 0");
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button btnStartCounter = new Button(this);
        Button btnChangeBackgroundColor = new Button(this);
        btnStartCounter.setText("Start counter");
        btnChangeBackgroundColor.setText("Change background color");

        btnChangeBackgroundColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (flagBackgroundColor) {
                    case 0:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        flagBackgroundColor = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        btnStartCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i;
                actionBar.setTitle("Counter: 0");
                for(i=0; i<10_000_000; i++) {
                    actionBar.setTitle("Counter: " + i);
                }
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(btnStartCounter);
        linearLayout.addView(btnChangeBackgroundColor);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

The second source code where I use a separated task for the incremental for loop is this:

```
package com.example.testasync;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    int flagBackgroundColor = 0;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Counter: 0");
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button btnStartCounter = new Button(this);
        Button btnChangeBackgroundColor = new Button(this);
        btnStartCounter.setText("Start counter");
        btnChangeBackgroundColor.setText("Change background color");

        btnChangeBackgroundColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (flagBackgroundColor) {
                    case 0:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        flagBackgroundColor++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        flagBackgroundColor = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        btnStartCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
                myTask.execute();
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(btnStartCounter);
        linearLayout.addView(btnChangeBackgroundColor);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            int i;
            actionBar.setTitle("Counter: 0");
            for(i=0; i<10_000_000; i++) {
                actionBar.setTitle("Counter: " + i);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the button for starting the counter I get the following error:

```
 Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Searching on Internet I discovered that for problems like this the solution is to use runOnUiThread() but doing so I get the same result of the first source code: app stucks waiting for the counter ending. 
How can I show the incremental value of the counter on the Action Bar without freezing the UI? Is there a way for accessing and modifying the Action Bar content from another thread? Is there another kind of approach that I don’t know?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Handler? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm a newbie in Andoird development and I'm following some videotutorials on the Net and none of them spoke about Handler when speak about Tasks and Threads. Now I'm going to see your link. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can access UI straight away

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Access UI code from here
    }
});
```

Or you can utilize a callback

### Starting with the interface

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void count(int i);
}
```

### How to start the task and receive the callback

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(new MyCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void count(int i)
    {
        actionBar.setTitle("Counter: " + i);
    }
});
myTask.execute();
```

### Extending your MyTask to include the callback

```
static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private MyCallback _callback;

    MyTask(MyCallback callback) {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            _callback.count(i);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first snippet (the one using Handler) produces the same effect of my first code (the app stucks until counting ends)  and the second suggestion doesn't start the counter. (if MainActivity implements the interface what I have to write into the count method in the MainActivity body?)

Comment: You're right, sorry, bit tired and I didn't write that in a compiler. You're right, implementing the interface in the activity isn't necessary.

Comment: @filograndipad2 I edited the answer, can you try out that example?

Comment: Many thanks for your help Ezzy. I followed exactly the new suggestions but now I get the error "Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." when i click the button for starting the counter.

Comment: @filograndipad2 you can wrap the `actionBar.setTitle("Counter: " + i);` in the Handler, but I'm pretty sure the UI might still freeze since it's called every few ticks. You could try though, that should get rid of the error at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onPostExecute` to  interact with the UI. Please read the [ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))

Notice:
`onPreExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()` are also can communicate with UI thread.
But `doInBackground` only be called from a worker thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Could you please show me how can I do that? I didn't understand reading the ref. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the number from "doInBackground" method. The AsyncTask class has method called `onProgressUpdate`. Just override it and update your ui from here. 
from your `doInBackground` method you call `onProgressUpdate(yourvalue)` and then update the UI. Please also note, that I changed the second type parameter of your asyncTask class from Void to Int.

(I implemented solution not in IDE, possible syntax errors possible, however the concept is like that)

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Int, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            int i;
            actionBar.setTitle("Counter: 0");
            for(i=0; i<10_000_000; i++) {
                publishUpdate(i)
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Overrdie
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Int.. ints){
        actionBar.setTitle("Counter: " + ints[0]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet but I continue to get "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." error

Comment: Oh, sorry, use publishProgress(i) method instead of onProgressUpdate() when you call it from your doInBackground. I updated the snippet